# Which Postgres value should I use in Django's DATABASE_ENGINE?

Tags: django, postgresql, psycopg2

It's my first time using PostgreSQL 8.4.2 with Django(I have always used MySQL or sqlite3 in the past).  Which value should I use for `DATABASE_ENGINE` in `settings.py`, `postgresql_psycopg2` or `postgresql`?  How do they differ from each other?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

## Update for Django 1.9

The `django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2` backend has been **renamed** to `django.db.backends.postgresql` in Django 1.9.  (The `psycopg2` name can still be used for backwards compatibility.)

*Essentially, for Django ≥1.9, use **`django.db.backends.postgresql`**.*

See note in Django's documentation for the [`ENGINE` setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATABASE-ENGINE).

#### History (Django ≤ 1.8)

`postgresql_psycopg2` and `postgresql` both use [psycopg](http://initd.org/pub/software/psycopg/), versions 2 and 1 respectively.  They are both implemented as C extensions using the libpq API to PostgreSQL.

**`postgresql_psycopg2` is currently recommended** -- the original author has deprecated version 1 and is only making [new releases of version 2](http://initd.org/pub/software/psycopg/ChangeLog-2.0).

When Django was originally released, psycopg2 was still in beta and was not recommended, but this has long since [changed](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/3364).

Comment: But can you explain me what are cons of using only postgresql ? and some benefits of postgresql_psycopg2.