# Closing django ORM connections in a multi-threaded environment

Tags: python, django, postgresql, multithreading, pgbouncer

I have below code in standalone script which is using django orm (outside django) with multithreading.

```py
import threading 

MAX_THREADS = 30
semaphore = threading.Semaphore(value=MAX_THREADS)

books = Books.objects.all()
for book in books:
    book_id = book.id
    t = threading.Thread(target=process_book, args=[book_id])
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

    for t in threads:
        t.join()

def process_book(book_id):
    semaphore.acquire()
    book = Books.objects.get(id=book_id)
    # Do some time taking stuff here
    book.save()
    semaphore.release()
```

Once the number of threads reaches `MAX_CLIENT_CONN` setting of postgres (which is 100 by default), I start getting following error with further calls:

> operationalError at FATAL: remaining connection slots are reserved for
> non-replication superuser connections

Researching this I got to solutions of using a database pooler like [pgbouncer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40270320/1330355), However that only stalls the new connections until connections are available but again after django's query wat timeout I hit

> OperationalError at / query_wait_timeout server closed the
> connection unexpectedly   This probably means the server terminated
> abnormally    before or while processing the request.

I understand that this is happening because the threads are not closing the db connections they are making but I am not sure how to even close the orm call connections? Is there something I could be doing differently in above code flow to reduce the number of connections?

I need to do a get on individual instances in order to update them because `.update()` or `.save()` wont work on queryset items.

Answer (score 0):

this update the field in all the books on the database

```
for book in books:
    Books.objects.filter(id=book.id).bulk_update(book, ['field to update'])
```

update each single book

```
def process_book(book_id):
    semaphore.acquire()
    book = get_object_or_404(Books, id=book_id).update(field)   # Do some time taking stuff here

    semaphore.release()
```

Comment: Didn't quite get it. How is this reducing number of connections?

Answer (score 0):

Just close the database connections at the end of your threads

```
from django import db

def process_book(book_id):
    semaphore.acquire()
    book = Books.objects.get(id=book_id)
    # Do some time taking stuff here
    book.save()
    semaphore.release()
    db.connections.close_all()
```